# On the interval $[0, 2\pi)$?...

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

Here is the problem:

For the interval $[0, 2\pi)$ find all exact solutions to $\tan 2x\cos 2x = \sin 2x$.

The farthest I've gotten is getting the identity for $\tan 2x$ and $\cos 2x$. I need to fully understand the process of finding the solutions. Any help or links to proper explanations is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $\tan(2x)$ is defined then $x$ is a solution. If $x$ is a solution then $\tan(2x)$ is defined. So finding all solutions in $[0,2\pi)$ is equivalent to finding all points $x$ in the interval where $\tan(2x)$ is defined. $\tan(x)$ is not defined when $x=\frac{\pi}{2}+k\pi$ for $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ so $\tan(2x)$ is not defined when $2x=\frac{\pi}{2}+k\pi$ which is to say when $x=\frac{\pi}{4}+\frac{k\pi}{2}$. From here I would just start listing the points where $\tan(2x)$ is not defined:

$$x \in \{-\frac{\pi}{4}, \frac{\pi}{4},\frac{3\pi}{4},\frac{5\pi}{4},\frac{7\pi}{4},\frac{9\pi}{4},\dots\}\qquad (1)$$
So, I see that $-\frac{\pi}{4}$ is too far to the left on the real line and $\frac{9\pi}{4}$ is too far to the right on the real line, so I just want the points which lie in $[0,2\pi)$ which amounts to saying that we must disclude those points listed in $(1)$ that lie in that interval.

Comment: Thank you! After studying, it makes sense to me.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

Prove that an exact solution  is a real $x$ where $\tan(2x)$ exists.